# jquery/js - Using click function animate.css to animate and show another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm refering animate.css from this site http://www.telegraphicsinc.com/2013/07/how-to-use-animate-css/ 
1- I have click function :

```
function animationClick(element, animation){
    element = $(element);
    element.click(
        function() {
            element.addClass('animated ' + animation);        
            //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
            window.setTimeout( function(){
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 2000);         

        });
}
```

2- I'm called the function here,but I want to change a bit,if i'm clicking the (#container) it will animate and show (.content) below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').each(function() {
        animationClick(this, 'bounce'); // how I modified this line
        $('.content').show(); // I want to show and animate bounce for (.content) not (#container)
    });
});
```

Comment: `animationClick($('.content'), 'bounce');`

Comment: thanks,for default (.content) is hide,but how to show (.content)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem :)

```
 $(function() {  
        $("#container").click(function() { 
           $(".content").show(); 
            animate(".content p", 'animated bounceInDown');  
            return false;  
        });  
    });  

    function animate(element_ID, animation) {  
        $(element_ID).addClass(animation);  
        var wait = window.setTimeout( function(){  
            $(element_ID).removeClass(animation)}, 1300  
        );  
    }
```